# How to generate JSON file from JSON Schema with addition of data in C#

Tags: c#, json, sql-server

I am currently working on an application that will convert the SQL Query Result to JSON. However the converted JSON must fit into a part of JSON Schema. I had done the first part and also load the Schema into the application, however I have no idea how to generate a JSON file based on the Schema I loaded and also filled in the data that I get from the SQL Query Result.

Here is the part of the sample of schema:

```
"security": [
 {
   "Default": []
 }
],
"components": {
"schemas": {
  "Event": {
    "title": "Event",
    "required": [
      "object",
      "body"
    ],
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "object": {
        "type": "string",
        "description": "The object name involved in the event",
        "enum": [
          "business_partners"
        ]
      },
      "body": {
        "type": "object",
        "description": "The core data of the event",
        "required": [
          "name1",
          "country",
        ],
        "properties": {
          "name1": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "Partner Name 1"
          },
          "name2": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "Partner Name 2"
          },
          "country": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "Country ISO Code"
          },
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

From the query result, I can have the property `name1`, `name2` and `country`.

After converted to JSON, the query result JSON looks like this:

```
 [
  {
    "Partner Name 1": "Jenny",
    "Partner Name 2": null,
    "Country ISO Code": "US",
  },
  {
    "Partner Name 1": "John",
    "Partner Name 2": "Alan",
    "Country ISO Code": null,
  },
]
```

How can I generate the JSON file with all the other fields in the schema but only filled the value from SQL Query Result into the JSON file?

I'm using `Newtonsoft.Json` and `Newtonsoft.Json.Schema` in this project.

NOTE: Other than the data returned by SQL Query Result, my JSON file generated also need those fields that does not exist in the query result.

Here is my code so far:

```
    private IEnumerable<dynamic> ReaderToAnonymmous()
    {
        //Connect to SQL Database using App.config
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SQLConnection"].ToString();
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        //Using Stored Procedure to execute query (Full Script Written inside SQLScript folder)
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select_Result_Convert_JSON", connection)
        {
            CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        };

        connection.Open();

        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            var schemaTable = reader.GetSchemaTable();

            List<string> colnames = new List<string>();
            foreach (DataRow row in schemaTable.Rows)
            {
                colnames.Add(row["ColumnName"].ToString());
            }

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var data = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, Object>;
                foreach (string colname in colnames)
                {
                    var val = reader[colname];
                    data.Add(colname, Convert.IsDBNull(val) ? null : val);
                }

                yield return (ExpandoObject)data;
            }
        }
    }

private void LoadSchema()
{
    using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText("..\\..\\sampleschema.json"))
    using (JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(file))
    {
        schema = JSchema.Load(reader);
    }
}

public void generateJSONFile(string fileName)
{
    try
    {
        var ObjectData = ReaderToAnonymmous(); //Get the SQL Query Result and Convert it to object
        LoadSchema();

        var Json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ObjectData);
        JArray BP = new JArray(Json);

        if (BP.IsValid(schema))
        {
            BP.Merge(schema);
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName)) //If user enter any file name
            {
                string basePath = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", "C:\\", fileName, ".json");

                using (StreamWriter file = File.CreateText(basePath)) //Create JSON File based on input name
                {
                    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                    serializer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented; //Format the JSON
                    serializer.Serialize(file, BP);
                }
           }
        }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error Message", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
   } 
}
```

Please please help! Thank you!

Comment: 1) load the data you need from the database into a C# object, then 2) convert it to another C# object that matches the json structure you need, and finally 3) serialize that object into a json string

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply! I have done the first part which the data from database is a Dictionary now. How can I do the second part which is convert it into another object that match the schema? Any method from Newtonsoft able to do that? Thank you!

Comment: You can auto-generate a c# file from the json schema either by code using newtonsoft.json or online using different websites. Once you have such an object, you can use an ORM to map the results of a select statement to it's properties (Dapper is my personal favorite), and then just serialize that object to json.

Comment: @Corene it would help if you could post some of your code. BTW why don't you use a list of custom objects instead of a Dictionary??

Comment: @RuiJarimba Sorry for late reply as I do not have internet access back in the home this few days. I have posted my code for C#. About the dictionary.. that's actually a way I found on internet too, didn't know could use objects as well...

Comment: @ZoharPeled I was suppose to create an application that can do the mapping yeah. I will look into the example you provided. Thank you so much!